# How would I break or stop a running flow in node-red?

Tags: node-red

I am new to node-red and have a very basic question. How would I break or stop a running flow in node-red?

Is it possible to stop execution if a desired condition is met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the `settings.json` (location listed in the startup log) you should find a section `runtimeState`

```
...
    runtimeState: {
        /** enable or disable flows/state endpoint. Must be set to `false` to disable */
        enabled: true,
        /** show or hide runtime stop/start options in the node-red editor. Must be set to `false` to hide */
        ui: true,
    },

...
```

The defaults are false, but if you change them to true you should get a Start/Stop option on the drop down from the Deploy button:

[image]

You can also toggle it with curl, e.g.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:1880/flows/state -d '{"state": "stop"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in way to "break" or stop a flow midway like you would in a traditional programming language with a `break` statement. However, you can design your flow to cease operation based on certain conditions by using conditional nodes like the `switch` node or function nodes with custom JavaScript code.

Comment: Has anyone developed a custom node to allow you to break and start a running flow without killing the flows in the command prompt?  Really strikes me as being a design flaw in the editor.

Comment: Why? the switch node does exactly what you want, why add a second way to do something